# JavaScript Functions Not Working iOS (Geolocation & Hamburger Icon)

Tags: javascript, ios, progressive-web-apps

The following code doesn't work on iOS but works perfectly on Android/PC:

```js
//lat long distance calculate
function arePointsNear(checkPoint, centerPoint, km) {
  var ky = 40000 / 360;
  var kx = Math.cos(Math.PI * centerPoint.lat / 180.0) * ky;
  var dx = Math.abs(centerPoint.lng - checkPoint.lng) * kx;
  var dy = Math.abs(centerPoint.lat - checkPoint.lat) * ky;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= km;
}

function start() {
    if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  /* do our magic */
            alert("We are now tracking your location");
    setInterval(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    data => {
        console.log(data);
        tempCoords.push([data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude]);
        window.localStorage.setItem('coords', JSON.stringify(tempCoords));
    })

    let homeLatLong = homePosition[0];
    let currentlatLong = tempCoords[0];
    var inside5km = arePointsNear({
      lat: homeLatLong[0], lng: homeLatLong[1]
    }, {
      lat: currentlatLong[0], lng: currentlatLong[1]
    }, 0.1);
    console.log(`Is this dumbass inside 5km?: ${inside5km}`);

    if (!inside5km) {
      outsideZoneNotif();
      tempCoords.length = 0;
    } else {
      insideZoneNotif();
      tempCoords.length = 0;
    }
  }, 15000);
} else if (Notification.permission === "blocked") {
    alert("Please Enable Notifications!");
 /* the user has previously denied push. Can't reprompt. */
} else {
  /* show a prompt to the user */
    alert("Please Enable Notifications!")
}
}
```

Also hamburger icon doesn't work, but the the set home button works? At first i thought it might be the permissions because theres no prompt but then it would still display an alert of some sort... You can check out the site [here](https://lockdowntracker.app) and see for yourself. I'm using materialize as a framework, could that not be compatible with iOS/safari?

Comment: I can see a missing ; at the end. Little syntax things like that kill you in Safari. Add a 'use strict' at the top of your script. I bet it will break in Chrome as well.
Somewhere in your code you have some sort of minor syntax error.

Comment: @ChrisLove I just tried that, hoever it did not work... Were you talking about the missing semi colon at ```alert("Please Enable Notifications!")```? that is what i corrected. I put a 'use strict' at the very top of my main.js but nothing is working.

Comment: If you have a Mac you can do some limited remote debugging on an iPhone. Other than that you will need to add some extra code to catch syntax errors. I hate Apple and this is one of the main reasons why....